# Как подключить JavaScript к Android-проекту?

Tags: javascript, java, android

Столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с подключением JS к Android. После долгого поиска так и не смог понять, как это сделать. Сам я только начинаю погружаться в мобильную разработку, а сделать приложение нужно в кратчайшие сроки.

В самом проекте мне нужно запускать html игры, но без js они отображаются некорректно.

Comment: напиши подробнее зачем тебе js. и что ты на нем хочешь делать. js  в мобильной разработке - это  reactNative .. и напрямую  он как бы не пересекается с  разработкой под андроид. или ты webView используешь? или еще что.

Comment: У меня есть html-игра. В ней есть папка с со файлами .js. Саму папку я перенес в проект, указал путь к index.html и в эмуляторе показывается страница самой игры, но не полностью. Понял, что не хватает моста между js и java. Как это прописать, не знаю

Comment: Пробывал строку mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
Она дает нужный результат, но только строка эта с предупреждением. Понял, что это связано с защитой java от js-внедрения, в котором может быть вредоносный код.
Как можно сделать по-другому, чтобы приложение и сам смартфон был защищен в этом плане?

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть несколько вариантов
1) Опробован мною:
    https://phonegap.com/
    создаешь аккаунт, загружаешь html, js, сss.
    и сервис превращает это все в APK файл для андроид.
    там еще конфиги надо прописать, по инструцуии(есть в документации на сайте)

Comment: Спасибо за вариант! А можно сделать так, чтобы этот сервис скомпилил мне несколько таких игрушек, чтобы я мог потом в одном приложении запускать их, выбирая из списка?

Comment: можно упаковать несколько html страниц, сделай хоть как обычный сайт например:
index.html game1.html game2.html и в index кинь на них ссылки!

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще похожий вариант:
Использовать http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/
Создаете первый экран, добавляете на него блок WebViewer, добавляете ему ссылку на свой проект и компилируете либо apk для скачивания и последующего размещения в Google Play, либо QR код, 
по которому через приложение "MIT AI2 Companion" https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.mit.appinventor.aicompanion3&hl=ru сможете открывать свой проект

Если ВЫ собираетесь тестировать и производить отладку, то отличным вариантом будет

- добавления файла manifest и объявление его в вашем коде  [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Манифест](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82) что позволит создать ярлык на экране телефона и открывать вашу страничку как приложение
- включение на телефоне dev-mode http://androidmir.org/android/4901/
- отладка приложения в Google Chrome - DevTools  (как Remote Device)

Comment: Хорошее решение, но, думаю, в моем случае он мне не подойдет. Хотелось бы что-нибудь, что прописывается в самом коде, без использования сторонних компиляторов.

Comment: Вы можете только последние пункты использовать, т.е. с помощью манифеста указывать браузеру открывать страницу как приложение без строк ввода, в нужной ориентации и т.п.  Ничего нигде регистрировать не придется ))))   Только пользователю открыв страницу в браузере на телефоне выбрать - добавить на главный экран.   Универсальное решение для html5 и к тому же это работать будет и на IOS
Посмотрите эту статью https://habr.com/ru/post/275849/